# Golang client for Cassandra

Tags: go, cassandra

I am looking for a golang client for Cassandra with unit testing support. I have found some libraries like

1. Goosie (not maintained any more)
2. gocql (any client library with no testing support is useless for me)
3. gocassa (same issue as above)

Can someone suggest me any client lib that has what I am looking for ?

Comment: What do you mean by testing support? gocql is by far the most matured and heavily contributed.

Comment: We use gocql and can unit test with it.  It does require us to define our own interface which acts mainly as a proxy to the underlying gocql client code, but allows us to replace the implementation with a stub or mock.

Comment: @sberry The *gocql.Session that we use in gocql for interacting with cassandra is not a interface. How do you provide mock implementation ? Can you point me to any code you have ?

Comment: You can create your own interface, one type that is implemented with a gocql session and one type that is used for mocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple example of what I was referring to in the comments:

```
type CassAPI interface {
    GetFoo(rowKey string) (someType, error)
}

type CassWrapper struct {
    cass *gocql.Session
}

func (cw *CassWrapper) GetFoo(rowKey string) (someType, error) {
    // do things with cw.cass
    return someType
}
```

In the application code, an instance of CassWrapper would be used, and in tests an instance of some mock or stub would be used which adhered to the same interface of CassAPI.

Comment: But how is the state of the database used?  For example, if a read in Cassandra is supposed to fail, how can the mock code know to signal the failure?